# Can I use the adjective 'haunted' to speak about a person?

Tags: word-usage

A person sees ghosts or is under attack by ghosts.

Which one is correct?

- My father is **haunted**.
- My father is **being haunted**.

Any alternatives?

Comment: Correct *for what*? Chances are pretty good there are a lot of situations in which you could use each of those, some of which even overlap, and I'm not sure we can get you a good general rule that applies to all of them.

Comment: Why would you not use _haunted_ to refer to a person? What does your dictionary tell you about this word? Can you use the [edit] link to tell us what you have learned about the verb _haunt_?

Answer (score 4):

Usually spirits, or ghosts, **haunt accommodations**, or locations. In the UK there is more than one [website](http://www.haunted-britain.com/) dedicated to haunted mansions, castles, stately homes, hotels and even pubs.  A house is said **to be haunted** when unexplained happenings occur: a picture that falls from a wall, a door that shuts suddenly, a vase which crashes on the floor. Things begin to be really creepy when people claim to see the image of a dead person (i.e. a ghost) waft in and out of one or more rooms.

The OP wishes to know whether a person can be haunted in English, the short answer is "yes" but not always in the way the OP believes. **A person can be haunted by a memory** or **by a problem**.

> - “All her life she was **haunted by feelings** of inferiority”
> - "It seems a strange thing to admit in an interview," says Liam Pieper, "but it's something that's **haunted me since I was very small**."
> - “She was **haunted by memories** of tattered wings of fairies, a garden where odd dreams grow, and a book whose pages refused to be read.”
> - “For years she was **haunted by guilt**”

Online there are many instances of people said to be haunted by ghosts, I'm not very keen on this usage, because I tend to think that spirits haunt buildings or areas such as a thicket, a wood, or a forest, and not people. Nevertheless, the following are perfectly grammatical.

> - Nicole Kidman reveals she was **haunted by the ghost of** Thailand's Death Railway
> - Jenny Mollen, Jason Biggs's wife, thinks she was **haunted by a ghost**
> - The memory of fallen friends haunted Salinger for years, just as Holden was **haunted by the ghost of his brother**
> - [‘In my younger days I was **haunted by the ghosts of** piglets, and the memory of those phantom piglets snuffling at my feet remains a source of trauma for me even today.’](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/haunt)

Therefore, the OP should write

1. My father is haunted **by** ghosts
2. My father is being haunted **by** ghosts.

Comment: Your proposal changes the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter Yes, it changes the meaning significantly   because the OP pointed out that the person is being attacked **by** ghosts or **seeing** ghosts. A person who is (*literally*) haunted is someone who has demons, or malignant spirits inside him or her. In that case Peter's answer should be selected. I don't have any problems with his interpretation.

Comment: You can be a "haunted person" which means you are tormented by visions or by a problem, but then it's an adjectival noun. Would "haunted father" express the meaning that he is visited or attacked by ghosts? Not without greater context.

Answer (score 1):

Both your sentences

> My father **is** haunted.
>   My father **is being** haunted.

are correct and can mean either *something* (not necessarily ghosts) are chasing or bothering or preoccupying your father. Additional context would be needed to determine the type and cause of the *haunting*.

**Haunting** can be physical or psychological.

> Haunted house are very popular around Halloween.
>
> He was haunted by his memories of war

Other possible synonyms are

> possessed
>   bedeviled